On macOS, how can I tell whether the WiFi network I'm connected to has both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz channels?
I'm connected to a WiFi network. When I hold Option and click the WiFi icon in the menu bar, it says that I'm connected to the 5 GHz band:

How can I check whether this WiFi router also supports the 2.4 GHz band on this SSID?

What problem are you trying to solve by knowing this info?

How do you check?  You ask the administrator of the network in question.

There is macOS built-in app Wireless Diagnostics.
Open the app, ignore pop-up window "Introduction". Instead from menu bar Window -> Scan. Information regarding Wifi networks will be displayed including column "Band".
